# History.js and manual refresh of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, history.js

i'm working with History.js and i'm trying to obtain an url as Google Plus urls.

```
(function(window, undefined){


var History = window.History; // Note: We are using a capital H instead of a lower h
if ( !History.enabled ) {
     // History.js is disabled for this browser.
     // This is because we can optionally choose to support HTML4 browsers or not.
    return false;
}


History.Adapter.bind(window, 'statechange', function(){ // Note: We are using statechange instead of popstate

    var State = History.getState(); // Note: We are using History.getState() instead of event.state
    History.log(State.data, State.title, State.url);
    console.log(State.data.page);
});



$('.item').live('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).children(1).attr('href');
    $(document).remove('#content');
    $('#loaded').load('/controlpanel' + url + '.php #content');
    History.pushState({page: url + '.php'}, "Prova Pagina", History.getRootUrl() + 'controlpanel' + url); // logs {state:1}, "State 1", "?state=1"
});
```

})(window);

this script works when I click on the link, but when I manually refresh the page, and I've already clicked on a link and the url becomes http://www.mysite.com/something/page, the browser gives me an 404 Error.
How can I solve it?

I would like to obtain something like: https://plus.google.com/explore

Comment: did you managed to find any solution to your question above? If yes, please reply back. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Even though JS allows you to not reload the whole page, the URL should still be accessible on the server side, so that someone accessing directly the link will see something (not to mention graceful degradation).

Also, you have to add a click handler on the anchor links, so that you can prevent the default action (going to the link) and use the `pushState` method to change the URL. Something like this:

```
document.body.onclick = function( e ) {
    var evt = e || window.event,
        target = evt.target || evt.srcElement // Get the target cross-browser

    // If the element clicked is a link
    if ( target.nodeName === 'A' ) {

        // Use the History API to change the URL
        History.pushState() // Use the library correctly

        // Don't forget to return false so that the link doesn't make you reload the page
        return false
    }
}
```

This is definitely not production code (you should check for external links, not bind on the body, etc), but you get the idea.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But how can I obtain something like google, giving to the user and to the server a valid URL when is necessary to reload the page manually?

This script is working if I stay in the same page and just click on the anchor links and is also working if I click the back button of the browser...